ISSUE: id title must be an integer
In the case of a contact import, I changed the titles values in CiviCRM so that Miss and Mister match my labels.
Then, after the import test and after the import, I get quantity of rows in error: prefix_id is not a valid integer
It turns out that at the time of changing the securities values, I was not informed of this. Should we not warn the user to put only values of type int? Notice to developers ;-)

I'm guessing you mean 'option values' where it says 'securities values' ?  (Translation issue??)
The values are usually integers but are not limited in the schema to int's so it looks like something in the import code is overly restrictive.

You're right, translation issue. I mean 'titles values': Madam is value 1 and Mister is value 3.
